# How to set environment variables in travis-ci and access them from python script?

Tags: python, environment-variables, travis-ci, nosetests

Our `travis.yml` looks like this:

```
language: python
python:
  - "2.7"
env: 
  - "MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost/"
services: mongodb
# command to install dependencies
install: "pip install -r requirements.txt"
# command to run tests
script: nosetests
```

Then in the python script with the tests, the line

```
server.connect(os.environ['MONGO_URL'])
```

throws an error (shortened):

```
File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
```

This error only occurs on *travis*. If we run them locally, it works without a problem. So we assume we set the environment variable `MONGO_URL` in a wrong way. We already tried ommitting the quotation marks, but it did not help.

Any hints? We use the free cloud service of *travis-ci*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works perfectly fine now, the error was that I accidently created another `travis.yml` missing the `.` in front of it - so the actually executed `.travis.yml` did not contain the environment variables.